# How to set mindate datepicker in fragment kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need help to set min date in a datepicker. The example shows today in the datepicker and should disable picking yesterday or earlier:

```
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etDates2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/et_style"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:hint="@string/date"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/et_calendar3"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15.3dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and datefragment.kt like this below:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.Dialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.DatePicker
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.greenhcm.android.common.function.toDateFormat
import com.greenhcm.android.common.function.toTimeMilis
import java.util.*

class DatePickerFragments : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private lateinit var action : (String) -> Unit
    private var maxDate : String? = null
    private var minDate : String? = null

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), this, year, month, day).apply {
            maxDate?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let {
                datePicker.maxDate = it.toTimeMilis("yyyy-MM-dd")
            }
            minDate?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let {
                datePicker.minDate = it.toTimeMilis("yyyy-MM-dd")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        action("$year-${month+1}-$day")
    }

    fun setListener(
        maxDate: String? = null,
        minDate: String? = null,
        action: (String) -> Unit
    ) {
        this.action = action
        this.maxDate = maxDate
        this.minDate = minDate
    }
}
```

I am confused here. How to set mindate in datepicker here? Call from other fragments?

```
    etDates2.setOnClickListener {
            val newFragment = DatePickerFragment().apply {
                setListener {
                    setDate(it)
                }
            }
            newFragment.show(childFragmentManager, "timePickers")
        }
```

Parameter setDate :

```
private fun setDate(date: String){
    etDates2?.setText(date)
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/swD6M.png , i want show this mindate datepicker like this bro, need help

Comment: need help bro :(